# How to use ifstream in OOP properly?

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to make a Text reader class, where I read the data I need in a vector, then get that data in another class for a vector in there.

I have tried the same method in a scratch file, it worked fine, I could read the file and my objects got every single element from every single line from the text file.

But as I tried to do this in OOP, I just can't read the file, I put `cout` statements in the `do..while` loop, then it only executed once, of course just because of the `do`.

This code works well in a single cpp file:

```
void TxtReader::read(std::vector<Contacts> &contacts){
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    std::string phoneNumber;
    std::string birthPlace;
    std::string birthDate;
    std::string Profession;
    std::ifstream savedContacts("ContactList.txt");
    Contacts newContact = Contacts();
    do {
        std::getline(savedContacts, firstName, ';');
        std::getline(savedContacts, lastName, ';');
        std::getline(savedContacts, phoneNumber, ';');
        std::getline(savedContacts, birthPlace, ';');
        std::getline(savedContacts, birthDate, ';');
        std::getline(savedContacts, Profession, ';');
        newContact.setFirstname(firstName);
        newContact.setLastname(lastName);
        newContact.setPhonenumber(phoneNumber);
        newContact.setBirthplace(birthPlace);
        newContact.setBirthdate(birthDate);
        newContact.setProfession(Profession);
        contacts.push_back(newContact);
    } while (std::getline(savedContacts, firstName));
}
```

And this is how I want to use it:

```
void ContactDir::getList() {
    // contacts vector is a private member in the header file
    textReader.read(contacts);
}
```

As soon as I call this in the `main.cpp`, the `while` loop in it fails, probably it can not read the file, as it only executes once and my file has multiple lines:

```
//any other function in the contactdir class works

ContactDir contacts = ContactDir();
contacts.getlist();
```

The text file inside:

```
Walter;Greyson;03069990643;London;1991.11.16;Engineer;
Carl;Johnson;03069990120;Manchester;1996.10.10;Teacher;
Aaron;Ramsey;03069995103;Birmingham;1969.03.05;Unemployed;
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a question.  Please include a main() function and provide a [Compilable, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This helps us help you.  If you can make your problem as simple as possible while still creating the failure, it will help us isolate the issues that will make your code work correctly.  By providing a main() function, it saves time for the person trying to duplicate your error and help you.

Comment: Sure looks like you are calling getline() twice on firstName.  Once in the do loop and once in the while conditional.

Comment: I could guess, but it would be wise to submit a copy of your ContactsList.txt file.

Comment: I edited my post, there it is @Gardener

Comment: Now that i see your contactLists.txt file, the answer would be slightly different.  See my answer below.  My answer will not handle the semi-colon at the end of each line.  LEt me see what I can do.

Comment: See updated answer based on your contactList.txt file.  Note, that I have provided an [mcve].  That is what we mean when we ask that you create a main file and reduce your code down.  By doing this, it helps you to solve the problem.  You should be able to expand my solution back into your code.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Well, the main problem is that, reading the file works well in a single cpp file,where everything is in one file, but it doesn't work in multiple classes, my read function in the TxtReader class should read the file and change the values of a vector in another class, the ContactDir class, and that's where my ifstream fails

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  Please provide a [mcve].  Do you understand what it means to provide a [mcve]?  I  should be able to copy your code from the question and paste it into my IDE and compile it and get the same error that you are getting.  I provided you with a main() function, with all the #include statements.  You can copy my solution into any IDE, compile, and run.  Can you do the same for the members on SO?  That saves them time. I've got to go.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated question, I have modified the answer.  I find that when trying to read a file or a series of inputs from the console, I make fewer mistakes if I read each line as a string and then parse the words or tokens in the lines using an istringstream combined with an additional getline.

Your file lends itself very nicely to this.

For main.cpp, I chose to only use one while loop and to base that on the read of the first name.  The other getline()'s are inside that loop and use an istringstream for parsing up to each ';'.  Here is my main.cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>


struct Contact {
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
};

void read(std::vector<Contact> &contacts)
{
  std::string firstName;
  std::string lastName;

  std::ifstream savedContacts("ContactList.txt");
  Contact newContact = Contact();
  std::string input_line;
  while (std::getline(savedContacts, input_line)) {
    std::istringstream ss(input_line);

    std::getline(ss, firstName, ';');
    std::getline(ss, lastName, ';');
    newContact.firstName = firstName;
    newContact.lastName = lastName;
    contacts.push_back(newContact);
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<Contact> contacts;

  read(contacts);

  for(auto const contact: contacts) {
    std::cout << contact.firstName << " " << contact.lastName << "\n";
  }
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```